# Error in installing google chrome error is cannot install 'libappindicator3-1:amd64'

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04, lib

This message Got with GDebi package installer

and when used 'sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'

it shows 'Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable:amd64'

tried to install from ubuntu software also

Please help me

Any support would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable the "universe" repository.

**[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)**

Once you enable it, update your system and you should now be able to install google-chrome-stable.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed